# How to add a menu item dynamically with an image in MFC featurepack

Tags: c++, menu, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

In MFC featurepack i create a standard menu and set the ID of sub menu to the same command of toolbar button to take that button's image that toolbar is the one sent to this method

```
CMFCToolBar::AddToolBarForImageCollection
```

and also I use the

```
GetContextMenuManager()->AddMenu(L"Mymenu", IDR_ContextMenu1);
```

in the application and

```
theApp.GetContextMenuManager()->ShowPopupMenu(IDR_ContextMenu1,rect.left,rect.top,button);
```

in the show menu event

I need to know how to add a menu item with a specified icon at the run-time dynamically

Comment: You can't. Only toolbar images can be used in menu.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation about OnInitMenuPopup of your CMainFrame.